# How to get specific channel chat history using telegram bot api?

Tags: api, telegram-bot

I am using telegram bot api to get the chat history of a channel https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getupdates

my bot attached to the many channels and my query is that how to get chat history of any specific channel which is using my bot.

but when I am using getupdates method it shows all the message with all channel.

my query is how to get the solution using telegram bot API?

just like when we need to send a message to any specific channel using the used the https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxx/sendMessage?chat_id=@channel id&text=message

i need a solution where I can send channel id and get the specific channel chat history using telegram bot API

Answer (score 4):

> my bot attached to the many channels and my query is that how to get
> chat history of any specific channel which is using my bot

You cannot get the chat history of a channel using the bot API. However you can use the core API (tdlib e.t.c) to get the chat history. Alternatively you can try and **scrape** from the [posts widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/posts), but that is going to be too tedious.

> but when I am using getupdates method it shows all the message with all channel.

You can manually filter out the channels since the ID is always in the Update object. I would suggest you use a library for this since it would be easier to implement the logic.